# Custom module block holding DB calls

Tags: blocks

I am working on a project where I first was only designing the theme. However, I now need to create 5 already made custom pages or blocks in a page, which will be available as soon as theme is enabled.

Each page should hold its own code for grabbing information from external database. Now I am having a huge dilemma on deciding how to create those pages. Since there are DB calls made on each of them, I was suggested to create a custom module, which would display a block with the printed content from database. I tried creating "pvpstats.module" and "pvpstats.info" as normal for custom modules, and displaying it in sidebar_first. After I enable the module, nothing happens. The block is just not visible. I used the code below.

```
function pvpstats_block_info() {
  $blocks['pvpblock'] = array(
    'info' => t('Example Block'),
    'status' => TRUE,
    'region' => 'sidebar_first',
    'weight' => 0,
    'visibility' => 0,
    'pages' => 'admin*
coder*
node/add*
node/*/edit
node/*/devel
',
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
  * Implements hook_block_view().
  */
function pvpstats_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'pvpblock':
      $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
      $block['content'] = theblock_contents();
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

function theblock_contents() {
  return '
    $dbserver="serveradress"; 
    $dblogin="username";       
    $dbpass="dbpassword";     
    $dbname="databaseserver";    

                mysql_connect($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbpass);
                mysql_select_db($dbname);
                mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

                $vypis =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE (accesslevel < '1') AND (pvpkills > '0') order by pvpkills desc LIMIT 20"); 
                echo '<table><tr><td><center>Nick</center></td><td></td><td>Kills</td></tr>';
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($vypis))
                    {
                echo '<tr><td><font color="green">';
                echo $row["char_name"];
                echo '</font></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><font color="blue">';
                echo $row["pvpkills"];
                echo '</font></td></tr>';

                    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

The main point is that I need those blocks later included in my theme so that they are visible immediately after enabling the theme, if that is somehow possible.

Comment: As side note, you need to rewrite the code of `theblock_contents()`, since that is not Drupal code. You don't call any `mysql_` function in a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `theblock_contents` you are trying to return php code. Don't. Do not echo or print in it. If anything, build a string. It should look about like that:

```
/**
* custom html block
* @return string
*/
function theblock_contents() {
  $dbserver="serveradress"; 
  $dblogin="username";       
  $dbpass="dbpassword";     
  $dbname="databaseserver";    

  $result = '';

  mysql_connect($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbpass);
                mysql_select_db($dbname);
                mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  $vypis =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE (accesslevel < '1') AND (pvpkills > '0') order by pvpkills desc LIMIT 20"); 
  $result .= '<table><tr><td><center>Nick</center></td><td></td><td>Kills</td></tr>';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($vypis))
  {
    $result .= '<tr><td><font color="green">';
    $result .= $row["char_name"];
    $result .= '</font></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><font color="blue">';
    $result .= $row["pvpkills"];
    $result .= '</font></td></tr>';
  }
  $result .= '</table>';
  return $result;
}
```

It's worth to mention that your code was plainly invalid PHP, no matter if it was supposed to run in Drupal or not. You can't simply `return` PHP code as string and hope it'll be executed. Only the part about not using `echo` in hooks is really Drupal dependent.

**Important note:** if you want your modules to work stable, please don't use PHP SQL functions directly. Use [`db_select`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) to obtain data. Connecting to multiple databases is [pretty well documented](http://drupal.org/node/18429) too.

Comment: Of course after this you may encounter other bugs, but that will be another question.

Comment: Actually your answer resolved my issue without adding any to it. The PvP stats are now correctly displayed in the assigned region. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a block automaticly with a theme's region. (I've done it in a module.install file.) By default a block in not visible; you have to choose manually a theme's region, or you can use code similar to the following one to add it programmatically.

```
  $default_theme = variable_get('theme_default', 'bartik');
  $values = array(
    array(
      'module' => 'block',
      'delta' => 'pvpblock',
      'theme' => $default_theme,
      'status' => 1,
      'weight' => 1,
      'region' => 'sidebar_first',
      'pages' => '',
      'cache' => -1,
    ),
  );

  $query = db_insert('block')->fields(array('module', 'delta', 'theme', 'status', 'weight', 'region', 'pages', 'cache'));
  foreach ($values as $record) {
    $query->values($record);
  }
  $query->execute();
```

Comment: May i ask where should i include your code to make block visible? Is it in themes template.php or in pvpblock.module.php? Thank you

Comment: have you tried to set the block visible by the UI ? I mean on this page : "admin/structure/block/list/yourthemename"

Comment: The custom block is not visible for me to assing a region to it, under structure/blocks, after enabling the custom module. So i guess something went wrong in module code?

Comment: clear the cache :)

Comment: That was the first thing i tried but it didn't help.

Comment: carefull : TopPvP.module.php should be TopPvP.module and TopPvpP.info.txt should be TopPvpP.info

Comment: Yep the extension files are correct.

Comment: i've tried your code, hooks are correct. Pb is probably in theblock_contents() function. Try with a very simple theblock_contents() return 'test';

Comment: function theblock_contents() {
  return 'test';}     makes no difference :\

Comment: @rishariss If you are editing a module that is already enabled, you need to first disable it, and then re-enable it. Differently, Drupal will not know you changed your code.

Comment: @pico34 I resolved the issue, thank you for ur effort!